# Odd indentation after \newline, after Math text

Tags: line-breaking, inline

So this happens whenever I try to insert a new line in my source code:

[image: Weird indentation]

The center equation is no longer centered! Why does that happen? I can't seem to figure out how to center it. Here's the related source code:

```
\begin{center}

\begin{equation}
\frac{p_{0a}}{p_{a}}=(1+\frac{\gamma-1}{2} M_{a}^2)^{\frac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}}
\label{p0/p}
\end{equation}

$\frac{p_{0a}}{19,000Pa}=(1+\frac{1.393-1}{2}0.85^2)^{\frac{1.393}{1.393-1}}$ \newline

$p_{0a}=30416.8 Pa$
```

I don't want the equation numbering on the second and third equations is why I haven't used `\begin{equation}`. I've tried using `\newline`, `\\\\`, and `\noindent` but nothing seems to work. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The math content of an `equation` is already centered (even without `center` env., the equation number isn't. If you don't want to have a number, use `\[....\]` instead, but in this case, the `\label ` is useless. Please consider to use `siunitx` as well for the numbers and units

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you for the explanation! Will keep this in mind

Comment: the `\begin{center}` isn't ended before your two "in-text" math lines.  for the first of those, the `\newline` forces a "long" line, but then you have a blank line which causes a paragraph break, and the next line is centered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using the `\begin{equation*} ... \end{equation*}` environment? This helps avoid the numbering of your equation.

Comment: This worked great! Thanks for the quick reply. It makes the equations look better too which is definitely better.

Answer (score 1):

The math content of the `equation` environment is already centered, the equation number is either left or right, so there's no need to use an external `center` environment.

The same is true for the `\[...\]` display math structure.

A suggestion with `\[....\]` and with `\begin{align*}...\end{align*}` and the numbered `align` version.

In my opinion the `align(*)` version is to be preferred here!

I've added `siunitx` to improve the look of the physical units and quantities.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mleftright}

\begin{document}


\[\frac{p_{0a}}{p_{a}}=(1+\frac{\gamma-1}{2} M_{a}^2)^{\frac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}}\]


\[\frac{p_{0a}}{19,000Pa}=(1+\frac{1.393-1}{2}0.85^2)^{\frac{1.393}{1.393-1}}\]


\[ p_{0a}=30416.8 Pa \]

\begin{align}
  \frac{p_{0a}}{p_{a}}&=\mleft(1+\frac{\gamma-1}{2} M_{a}^2\mright)^{\frac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}}\label{pressureequation} \\
  \frac{p_{0a}}{\SI{19000}{\pascal}}&=\mleft(1+\frac{1.393-1}{2}0.85^2\mright)^{\frac{1.393}{1.393-1}} \nonumber \\
  p_{0a}&=\SI{30416.8}{\pascal} \nonumber 
\end{align}


\begin{align*}
  \frac{p_{0a}}{p_{a}}&=\mleft(1+\frac{\gamma-1}{2} M_{a}^2\mright)^{\frac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}} \\
  \frac{p_{0a}}{\SI{19000}{\pascal}}&=\mleft(1+\frac{1.393-1}{2}0.85^2\mright)^{\frac{1.393}{1.393-1}} \\
  p_{0a}&=\SI{30416.8}{\pascal} 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, that certainly cleans things up quite a bit. Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Simply try `gather`and the `\notag` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}


\begin{gather}
  \frac{p_{0a}}{p_{a}}=\Bigl(1+\frac{\gamma-1}{2} M_{a}²\Bigr)^{\frac{γ}{\gamma-1}}\label{p0/p}\\
  \frac{p_{0a}}{19,000Pa}=\Bigl(1+\frac{1.393-1}{2}0.85²\Bigr)^{\frac{1.393}{1.393-1}} \notag\\[1ex]
  p_{0a}=30416.8 Pa \notag
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]